# CentOS 6: Group descriptors corrupted

Tags: linux, centos

I found the following in dmesg and I am wondering what I can do to fix it: `EXT4-fs (snumbd1d): group descriptors corrupted!`.

Will I need to take the server offline in order to recover the file system or is it possible to do it without taking the server offline?

```
EXT4-fs (snumbd1d): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum for group 128 failed (22619!=896)
EXT4-fs (snumbd1d): group descriptors corrupted!
snumbd_open_blk(blkid,65537): Disable access (515,210331,210331)...
snumbdctl_release(mms,223881): OK s=ffff88001f1ea000
snumbdctl_open(mms,223881): OK s=ffff88001f1ea000
session_init(mms,223881): OK. kdev=fc:1, len=16351232 sect=512 s=ffff88001f1ea000 pgrp=(210331).
snumbd_open_blk(blkid,65545): Disable access (515,210331,210331)...
snumbd_open_blk(udisks-part-id,65546): Disable access (515,210331,210331)...
snumbdctl_release(mms,223881): OK s=ffff88001f1ea000
```

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how you are using corrupted file system, you may need to run fsck to fix these error and for that you need to unmount the related mount point.

So you don't have to take complete system offline until issue is with / mount point (Or OS filesystem related).

Comment: How can I determine which partition is have this issue?

Comment: it should be `snumbd1d` i guess based on your shared logs, you can use `blkid` command to get more details about your partitions.

Comment: There is no device ```snumbd1d```. I looked in dev and there is a ```/dev/snumbdctl```. Do you know what this device is? It looks like a character device as the permissions are as follows: ```crw-------```.